# if I use deprecated header in FB ios SDK 3.x how long will my app still work

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm moving from 2.0 to 3.5.2 but some issue is still there. Some people in StackOverFlow suggest to use deprecated headers bundle with the SDK. May I know how long will my app still workable?

Comment: why would you want to use API's that are highly likely to go away in an upcoming iOS release?

Comment: So it's going away? because some issue with the workflow after upgrading he SDK, it might require an intensive changes in the app si it might not be possible to update for the time being as our client wants an update early. Thank you anyway. I think its best to hire some experience developer to make the changes asap